# Naked domain on Google Sites New

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, web-hosting, g-suite

I've been messing with my DNS settings and can't figure out how to get this to work...

I have G Suite for `example.com`, with a (new) Google Sites app published and accepting `www.example.com`. I have a CNAME in my DNS pointing `www` to Google, so `http://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` both work, with the `http` one doing a 301 to the `https` version, which is exactly what I want.

In my DNS (at GoDaddy), I have the base domain redirecting to `https://www.example.com` - so requests to `http://example.com` get forwarded properly.

The one leftover is `https://example.com/` - that one does not redirect because GoDaddy doesn't support it (I'd assume all hosting companies would be the same), but I want it to redirect like the others.

The only way I can think of is to have a live hosting account somewhere else, for `https://example.com/`, and have that redirect the browser over to `www`. I could do that with a static hosting (like Firebase) and use javascript, or app hosting with something like ASP.NET, and redirect directly in the response.

Is there an easier way, without using a separate hosting product?

Comment: If you're still with godaddy, I would switch to google registrar. it's cheaper and support SSL Redirects https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue almost 3 years later and it seems pretty clear that this is not possible through DNS/Google alone. You have to host somewhere separately with an SSL cert installed for the naked domain otherwise it won't work, so unfortunately the answer is: No

At least Google have updated their article to explicitly state that the redirect doesn't support https (some older posts I've found imply that this was not previously specified in the article.

Comment: "At least Google have updated their article" - which one, please?

Comment: This one, although I think they've updated the wording on the article again as this doesn't say exactly what my previous comment did: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373

Answer (score 0):

for Google see the instructions in Google admin help to redirect a naked domain: 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: This is not answering the question. You're linking to information that the OP has already configured. In essence, OP is asking: How to configure the naked domain with http*s* to also redirect?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and ended up solving it through a 3rd party:

- WWWizer does 301 redirects to the “www” subdomain for free.

More info: https://medium.com/code-procedure-and-rants/naked-domain-issues-with-google-sites-240fc7ae2d04